# removing a subset of numpy array from another numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm using numpy delete to remove a subset of an array
let's say we have the arr array:

```
arr = array([1, 8, 0, 3, 5, 7, 6, 9, 2, 4])

numpy.delete(arr, arr[:4], 0)
```

I'm expecting the first 4 rows to be deleted. But the output is:

```
array([0, 5, 7, 6, 9, 4])
```

Can anyone help me removing the subset of an array using numpy

Comment: Reread what `np.delete` says about the second `obj` argument!  It says **indices to be removed**, not **values**.  This isn't a `list` `del` clone.

Comment: *expecting the first 4 rows to be deleted* isn't it `arr[4:]`?

Comment: It's worth a check here: are you sure `delete` is what you want? If you want to "delete" from the beginning or end of an array, a slice is much faster, x = arr[4:]? It's not exactly the same as delete, but it's what would be most commonly used (because it's super fast) to get a trimmed version of the array.

Comment: yes, if it's at the beginning or end it's quite simple. But I have slices somewhere inside.